# Validation allow only number and characters in edit text in android

Tags: android

In my application I have to validate the `EditText`. It should only allow character, digits, underscores, and hyphens.

Here is my code:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                                        
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                              
    }
                                        
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
                                        
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // validation codes here
                                
        location_name=s.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),location_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
        
        if (location_name.matches(".*[^a-z^0-9].*")) {
            location_name = location_name.replaceAll("[^a-z^0-9]", "");
            s.append(location_name);
            s.clear();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Only lowercase letters and numbers are allowed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }                                   
    }

});     
                                    
location.add(location_name);
```

When I enter input into `EditText`, the application is force closed.

Comment: hi@kanna use edittext.setError("Only letters and digits allowed") for showing error message.

Comment: location_name=et.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^a-z^0-9^A-Z]", "");    /**et being your edit text. Get rid of that other stuff.  That's it.**/

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Instead of using your "manual" checking method, there is something very easy in Android:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                               int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 

        for (int i = start;i < end;i++) { 
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i)) && 
                !Character.toString(source.charAt(i)).equals("_") && 
                !Character.toString(source.charAt(i)).equals("-")) 
            { 
                return ""; 
            } 
        } 
        return null; 
    } 
}; 

edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Or another approach: set the allowed characters in the XML where you are creating your EditText:

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,_,-" 
  android:hint="Only letters, digits, _ and - allowed" />
```

Comment: I want to show the user like "Only letters and digits allowed".

Comment: that would go in the hint, i suppose

Comment: @kanna, as njzk2 mentionned, you can use the hint attribute to write this, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly..with this how can i add underscore and hypen also.

Comment: Actuaaly i have use edit text like final EditText locationname=new EditText(EmailActivity.this);, not in xml ..

Comment: This is a pretty nifty answer, but the top doesn't work on my S3 running 4.2.  It allows numbers and the allowed characters, but strangely only allows the first letter you touch and then repeats it.  Kinds of strange, if I have time I'll try to hone in on the issue.

Comment: @digiholic, strange... Maybe they changed the InputFilter on Android 4.2, but I don't think so.

Comment: Android doc say the following about 'digits': "If set, specifies that this TextView has a numeric input method and that these specific characters are the ones that it will accept." So, it doesn't look like you should use it for non-numeric input. I got some funky behavior when I tried.

Comment: The first option should have "&" not "||" s

Comment: no commas are necessary android:digits="0123ABCabc" is perfectly valid. If you wanted to include comma this would work as well ",0123ABCabc"

Comment: This will also allow the comma "," character. You may set digits like this:
`android:digits="0123456789*qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_-"` , Just remove all commas

Comment: @Miloš - @vicky-kapadia is right, the `if` statement should have `&&` in it, not `||`. This way it won't work. I'm suggesting an edit.

Comment: Just realized what @Ewoks mentioned, no commas are necessary in 'digits' property otherwise the user will be able to write them.

Comment: Does this implementation support all languages

Answer (score 20):

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,_,-" 
  android:hint="Only letters, digits, _ and - allowed"
/>
```

the above code will also include `,` additionally to avoid `,` use the following code

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_-"
  android:hint="Only letters, digits, _ and - allowed"
/>
```

Comment: what about space?space also is not allowed

Comment: To add space and Mayuscule:
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_- "

Comment: @giopromolla if you're moving that to strings.xml, it has to be `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqr‌​stuvwxyz0123456789_-\u0020`, otherwise the space gets trimmed.

Answer (score 14):

This can be useful, especially if your EditText should allow [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) (in my case, [Portuguese Diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_orthography#Diacritics)):

```
<EditText
   android:digits="0123456789AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZzÁáÂâÃãÀàÇçÉéÊêÍíÓóÔôÕõÚú"
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution similar to the `android:digits="0123456789*"`, is to use this:

```
EditText etext = new EditText(this);
etext.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789*"));
```

An added bonus is that it also displays the numeric keypad.

Comment: Works great, except you'll get yelled at by the ide, but minus that this works like a charm.

Comment: @TrevorHart looks like Inti figured it out and now it's correct! You shouldn't create a new instance, 'getInstance' is static. That's why IDE yells at you :D

Answer (score 4):

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
        int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.toString(source.charAt(i)).matches("[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+")) {
                return "";
                edittext.setError("Only letters, digits, _ and - allowed");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Comment: @Rams this code use regex to only allow character, digits, underscore and hypen.

Comment: buggy code. Sometimes clear the whole input.

Comment: @NoumanCh Hi Nouman, if input characters don't  match , it clear the whole input.You can remove thats part of code. line 7 ---> ( return ""; )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static SpannableStringBuilder getErrorMsg(String estring) {
        int ecolor = Color.BLACK; // whatever color you want
        ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ecolor);
        SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(estring);
        ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);
        return ssbuilder;
    }
```

Then `setError()` to EditText when you want show 'only Letters and digits are allowed' as below.

```
etPhone.setError(getErrorMsg("Only lowercase letters and numbers are allowed!"));
```

Hope this will help you. I use the same for Validation Check in EditText in my apps.

Answer (score 1):

please  try adding the **android:digits="abcde.....012345789"** attribute? although the android:digits specify that it is a numeric field it does work for me to set it to accept letters as well, and special characters as well (tested on SDK-7)

Comment: what's the difference between yours and my answer?

Comment: i think you are updated your answer... while i am answering the content which i have mentioned was not there in yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate this by two ways , both worked for me, hope will be helpful for you too.

**1> Mentioning the chars in your edittext .**

```
android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,_,-"
```

2> Can validate pragmatically as answered by milos [pragmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14192231/5886712)

Answer (score 0):

use this 2 function

```
public static boolean isdigit(EditText input)
    {

    String data=input.getText().toString().trim();
    for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
    {
         if (!Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i)))
                return false;

    }
    return true;
    }

    public static boolean ischar(EditText input)
    {

    String data=input.getText().toString().trim();
    for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++)
    {
         if (!Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i)))
                return true;

    }
    return false;
    }
```

pass Edittext variable in these function .. so you can have boolean value.