# How to find word Length of the Edittext in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, spell-checking

I have an `EditText` with 140 characters maximum length for typing. Now I have one button, when I click the button, the contents of the edit text should be printed on log cat. Up to this I have implemented.

But my question is, I should validate for words which means a continuous text without meaning (for eg. "ajldjlkdjkjfdjdjjd") should not be printed instead words should be checked say word length of 10 approx. for grammar. How to implement this ? any ideas would be helpful for me. thanks in advance.

**Note:-** I may type word as well as numbers, if i typed word without meaning it should alert a message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192199/validation-allow-only-number-and-characters-in-edit-text-in-android   see this

Comment: @rajshree - "But my question is, I should validate for words which means a continuous text without meaning (for eg. "ajldjlkdjkjfdjdjjd") should not be printed instead words should be checked say word length of 10 approx. for grammar. "

Comment: ok,you mean unwante dwords sholud not come??

Comment: How are anticipating to verify if the entered word has a meaning or not?

Comment: yes absolutely rajshree

Comment: @shoe rat, meaningful word only should be checked that is what my task.either i store in db or should handle in my logic

Comment: Yeah, but this does not answer the 'how' question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code snippet for that. add your code when length is proper or not.

```
    //Prepare object of Edit Text
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //Get String entered by user
    String enteredText = editText.getText().toString();
    //split string to get every word using _ (space) and add all word to an array
    String[] words = enteredText.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length() > 10) {
            //handle if any word is > 10 ch.
            break;
        }else{
             //handle if word is meaning full or not
        }
    }
```

Comment: Anil Savaj, as you said this logic works but the issue is if i entered the text without spaces then it doesn't work.

Comment: it worked after little changes to my program. thanks Anil Savaj for your help. But i need to implement the dictionary concept to achieve the correct output. Anyhow your answer helped hence i marked as correct one.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to achieve this.(Frankly speaking almost impossible.)

One solution could be - keep a local DB with a list of words, sorted based on word length.

Now, each time you get some text from the edit text, check the size of the String . If it is equal to 10, start by comparing all the words which have length = 10 in the DB.
YOU CANNOT COMPARE SUBSETS OF ENTERED TEXT.

example knowledge can be seen as know, now, ledge,edge ,led,owl etc..

You'll have to implement your own (complex) logic for a word-subset lookup.