# Need input restriction in AlertDialog

Tags: android, input, textview, android-alertdialog, restriction

Here comes my first question here.
I'm creating a dialog to enter a player name in a game menu, but want to restrict the possible characters (only letters and numbers, and if not possible at least exclude return) and prevent from pressing the ok-button if the field is empty, but I cannot figure out how to do this. Is there also a way of setting the default action on return to ok? I know many apps utilise this to make inputs faster. Here is what I have:

```
public String tmPlayerName;
```

...

```
public void playerDialog() {
    dialogOpen = true;
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Change player");
    alert.setMessage("Enter player name (cannot be empty)");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setText(tmPlayerName);
    input.
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            tmPlayerName = input.getText().toString();
            }
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            });

    alert.show();
}
```

EDIT: The application is built using Android 4.0 and is using Google Play Services if that is to any help.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14192231/2649012

Comment: The solution given in the link restricts me for entering anything.
Any ideas on how to restrict an empty submission?

Comment: The answer shown gives a solution for `want to restrict the possible characters (only letters and numbers` then it's very easy to reject an empty text `if(myEdt.getText().toString.equals("")){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex to make compare with the text input:

```
String reg = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
```

---

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


            alert.setTitle("Change player");
            alert.setMessage("Enter player name (cannot be empty)");
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);

            input.setText("test");

            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String tmPlayerName = input.getText().toString();
                    if(tmPlayerName.matches(reg)&&!tmPlayerName.isEmpty()){
                        Log.i("ALERT","Store username -"+tmPlayerName);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please put valid username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        }
               });

            alert.create().show();
```

If you want to make OK button is disable while it is empty... my suggestion is to use custom dialog. Try this example - http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Comment: Works as a very good workaround, but would like to have it even more restrictive, e.g. cannot press ok if text is invalid and only possible to enter the valid characters.  For some reason I can't get the InputFilter way to work properly either.

Comment: Please check my last Note.. 
If you want to make OK button is disable while it is empty... my suggestion is to use custom dialog. Try this example - http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application