# Android : Allow User to add only alphabets and special characters in an EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I want the user to enter only alphabets and special characters in an EditText. One approach would be to add all the alphabets and all the special characters in the EditText's "android:digits" tag. But I don't think that a good way.

Any better way to achieve it?

Comment: You can achieve this by programatically by addTextChangedListener

Comment: Okay. I'll give it a try.

Comment: why do you think that `android:digits` is not a good way ?

Comment: This can help ou. Just change to allow what you want in your EditText http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192199/validation-allow-only-number-and-characters-in-edit-text-in-android

Comment: @jaiSoni : Because I'll have to add a lot of special characters and there's a good chance that I might miss some. I was hoping to find a way to block just numbers. I think I've found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a InputFilter to block out only numbers :

```
private static InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        String blockCharacterSet = "1234567890";
        if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Then Applying the filter :

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [EditText input type docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) to find if any of these satisfy your requirement.

If not , using regular expressions to check input string from `EditText` is according to your required format or not is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz?/>,<.:";'{}[]\|)(*&^%$#@!`~+=-_ etc"` attribute in edittext inside your xml.
Note:- please add all available special characters in keyboard in place of etc.

Comment: it's not working: I am getting Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token). I want to allow only limited characters android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-/&^%$#@!" If I uses android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-/" then it works but I want to allow character &^%$#@! also from XML in Android.

Comment: I have a requirement where I need to allow only ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-/&^%$#@! character from soft input key