# An edittext should take only a character

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

An edittext should take only a character, but when given multiple characters the edittext accepts. It forces me to erase the given text. I want my edittext to necessarily accept any one of the texts "S,A,Q,W,R,B,C,D,E,U" and edittext shouldn't accept any other characters other than given characters in android. I need code in java, not in xml.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192199/validation-allow-only-number-and-characters-in-edit-text-in-android    Have a look :)

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568485/an-edittext-should-take-only-a-character/36568582#36568582) and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have written:

> i need code in java. not in xml.

Try this:

```
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("SAQWRBCDEU"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:digits="SAQWRBCDEU"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```