# EditText with only text, digit and underscore like Instagram ID

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an functionality in which I have to validate only characters, digits and underscore (No any other special characters) which is like Instagram ID.

I tried a lot. Even I used digit property in xml as well as InputFilter in my java class.

What is really issue?

1.) In some devices, it works perfect

2.) In some devices, when I pressed space key it automatically work as backpress in keyboard means it removes last character.

Please suggest me a proper solution to develop functionality like Instagram Id.

Thanks a lot
in advance

My xml is here,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edUniqueID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:digits="_1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: show your xml code with digit property

Comment: Check I add my `EditText` @ Parsania Hardik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validation allow only number and characters in edit text in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192199/validation-allow-only-number-and-characters-in-edit-text-in-android)

Comment: Not working in my case. I already used. @ Nerevar

Comment: bro your xml working in my studio . I checked it .

Comment: Yes but it not working on MOTO G3, LETv. Check in multiple device if you have. @ Sushil Kumar

Comment: @HarshPatel please have look on my answer . I think you found some mistake in your code .....................

Comment: @HarshPatel Try and Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Try using this.**

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm,_" 
/>
```

**EDIT :**

`Without Comma (,) you can use as this`.

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_"
/>
```

Comment: Its working fine in all but it also include "," (Coma) in EditText.

Comment: @HarshPatel If you Required to include comma then keep it otherwise you can also use this `android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_"`.

Comment: @ jaydroider If I used without coma it got a same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> You can implement this programmatically use below code

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))
                        || !Character.toString(source.charAt(i))
                                .equals("_")
                        || !Character.toString(source.charAt(i))
                                .equals("-")) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

> Hope this will help you

Comment: Which device you have??? Just Give me full description of your device. I've Motorola G3

Comment: can you please tell me your device version ?

Comment: actually it doesn't work as well in newer Androids (like 4.0+).