# Specific number of characters as letters and the succeeding characters as numbers

Tags: android

I want the user to type only letters in the first 5 characters and the next characters would only be numbers.

I've read the answer from this link: [Validation allow only number and characters in edit text in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192199/validation-allow-only-number-and-characters-in-edit-text-in-android/14192231)

However when I tried to do what I wanted to do, I'm getting error saying this:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
>                                                                                       at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)

The codes I've tried to do what I want.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                                           int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                    for (int i = start;i < etLettersAndNumbers.getText().length();i++) {

                        if (etLettersAndNumbers.getText().length() < 4) {
                            if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }

                        if (etLettersAndNumbers.getText().length() >= 4) {
                            if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            };
            etLettersAndNumbers.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {filter});
```

I'm using dynamic EditText.

Comment: Try this **`[a-zA-Z]{5}\d`** regex

Comment: I'm sorry, but where do I put that?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "type only  letters in the first 5 characters" and "next characters would only be numbers"?

Comment: @Rabee for example, ABCDE123456789,

Comment: Your current loop termination is on `etLettersAndNumbers.getText().length()` basis whereas I suppose it should be on 'end' parameter that you are receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 public void set(final EditText etLettersAndNumbers) {
    etLettersAndNumbers.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        int len = 0;

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String str = etLettersAndNumbers.getText().toString();
            char[] st = str.toCharArray();
            try {
                if (Character.isLetter(st[st.length - 1]) && st.length - 1 < 5) {
                    System.out.print("Nothing");
                } else if (!Character.isLetter(st[st.length - 1]) && st.length - 1 < 5) {
                    if(count>0)
                    etLettersAndNumbers.setText("");
                } else if (Character.isLetter(st[st.length - 1]) && st.length - 1 >= 5) {
                    if(count>0)
                    etLettersAndNumbers.setText("");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }

        }


    });
}
```

Comment: Crashes when I type beyond 5 characters and I was still able to type a letter at the 6th letter.

The error:
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Comment: I am using in my phone ,it is working fine. please check your code place. Are you using dynamic EditText ?

Comment: What do you mean dynamic EditText? :O I'm just using the EditText given by android studio hehe

Comment: Dynamic means :  EditText t = new EditText(this);

Comment: Oh, yes that's what I did. And added : .addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher() {....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168232/discussion-between-yazao-ruzakiaga-and-gautam-kushwaha).